# Tableau data calculation to distribute the data from value to other value in tha same column

Tags: tableau-api

[image]

The existing data if I build a table it looks like this ...but I was the value under not defined should be distributed equally among the other 3 fields or three-column how to do it ??

The result should look like the one below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any column names or information about your data, so I will assume that the field with "2020M12" value is called MonthYear and field with "Global", "Enterprise" etc. is called "Type".

Create a new calculated field called "Undefined Customers New to Cloud MOM" with the following formula assuming SUM is the preferred aggregation:

```
{FIXED [Type], [MonthYear]: SUM(IIF([Type]="Note Defined", [Cust New to Cloud MOM], NULL))}
```

Create another formula called "Cust New to Cloud MOM - Apportioned" with the following formula:

```
([Undefined Customers New to Cloud MOM]/3) + [Customers New to Cloud MOM]
```

You can make the 3 used in the formula above dynamic by using `COUNTD([Type])-1`